# What to wear in Amsterdam in end of June

Tags: netherlands, weather-and-climate, amsterdam, clothing

I'll be in Amsterdam end of June for 5 days. I'm from tropical weather and heard spring in Amsterdam is bit cold.

- Do I need wear clothing thats suits to cold weather or normal t-shirt and trouser will be fine?
- Will it be cold in nights? can I wear casual baggy shorts at night?

This question is about what to dress in End of June in Amsterdam.

PS: End of June 2017 was very cold and had some rain with wind. Even though it says end of spring don't forget to put some dress for cold weather.

Comment: FWIW, this week is very hot to the point that there is a warning out.

Comment: P.S. I forgot to add: you'll be in Amsterdam during summer, not in spring.

Comment: @user2473015: I've been probably the first one to vote to close, so maybe a little explanation needed after your edit. Recently, other questions like yours have been closed as duplicate, and it makes sense when you think that what to dress is all about your personal feeling with weather. For example I'm mostly "weather insensitive", I went through Dubai and Indonesia with a shirt and jeans and no hats, I just ignored the sun. I was in winter in Amsterdam during a storm and I was dressed like mild autumn in Italy and was without an umbrella. Do you really want advices by me on what to wear? :-)

Comment: Or you could ask what to wear in Indonesia, and get some advices by some Indonesian to cover as much as possible and wear gloves and scarf, and so on, just because many Indonesian of Chinese descent despise to be tanned (at least, that's the explanation I got). You can see German at the beginning of spring in north Italy with shorts, t-shirts and sandals while Italian are still wearing jackets and warming stuff... So, what to wear? Check the weather forecast, check the weather historical data, and dress accordingly: you are the only one who knows how badly rain or cold or hot can affect you.

Answer (score 5):

Spring in Amsterdam is generally cooler than it is in the south of Europe but it does not mean that the weather is really cold. The thing is that you cannot rule out a few weeks of 15ºC weather, wind or rain, especially in April-May, so you might want to pack something like a light jacket to be prepared. But you can expect plenty of warm weather as well.

Case in point: This week is very hot, close to 30ºC and there is a warning out, while the forecast for next week is rainy weather, 20ºC during the day and as little as 15ºC during the night.

Answer (score 1):

it is always a good idea to have a sweater (or a vest...)  with you in the evening if you are sensitive to cold.

Depending on what you intend to do in the evening ( eating out, going to a club or bar) maybe you should change to pants.

Comment: Yes I used to temperatures like 27°C to 30°C normally.

Comment: Advice to walk about Amsterdam in your [vest](http://www.marksandspencer.com/2-pack-pure-cotton-sleeveless-cellular-vests-with-staynew/p/p22286833?&pdpredirect) and [pants](http://www.marksandspencer.com/MSFindItemsByKeyword?searchTerm=pants&langId=-24&storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&categoryId=0&typeAhead=) may be misconstrued in some parts of the anglosphere. Most Dutch are pretty liberal-minded but you may feel cold.

Answer (score 1):

You should wear clothes. But, even that is not a definite.

You should already be able to get an idea of the weather in late June, now, by looking at the forecast.

That said, Dutch weather is a tad unpredictable. In June, it can be 35 degrees celsius during the day and under 10 degrees at night. Check out the climate chart on [the Wikipedia page for the Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands).